# Actualizar fila mysql al vencer date

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, date, mysql-workbench

Es posible crear del lado del servidor de base de datos mysql una función que actualice automáticamente una fila al vencer el un campo date en comparacion con la fecha actual.

Comment: Puedes crear un script en PHP que haga la actualización que necesitas y crear un evento cron que ejecute dicho script los días/horas/semanas/meses/años que desees. Aunque la pregunta no queda del todo claro, supongo que es más o menos eso lo que quieres.

Comment: Si tengo una dato en mi base de datos que automáticamente suma los dias que debe vencer entonces guarda esa fecha en cuanto termine la fecha el campo debe ser eliminado y campo debe quedar en blanco hasta que lo vuelvan a utilziar